# How to prove Poincaré inequality by using extension theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces

Poincaré inequality is stated as follows:

> Let $ \Omega $ be bounded, connected, open subset pf $ \mathbb{R}^n $, with a $ C^1 $ boundary $ \partial \Omega $. Assume that $ 1\leq p<\infty $ and $ u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega) $. Then there exists a constant $ C $, depending only on $ n, p $ and $ \Omega $, such that
> $$
> \left\|u-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}u\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\left\|Du\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}
> $$
> for each function $ u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega) $.

I have already know the proof from compactness argument. Now I want to prove this inequality by direct computation. First, I consider the condition that $ \Omega $ is convex and prove the inequality. Now I want to deal with the general case by using the extension theorem of Sobolev space. However, I can not deal with the error terms when using the theorem. Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: Hey! Did you figure out how to use the extension theorem? I am wondering the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that some useful information you can find in paragraph 1.5 of
"Differentiable Functions on Bad Domains" by V. G. Mazia, S. Pobozchi.